# X-acto knife with soldering iron (Durable?)

Tags: soldering, heat, damage

I know many people who like to use an x-acto knife on their soldering iron.  They use it to cut through plastic enclosures for their products.  But the question is, how long will the x-acto knife last with the heat?

Comment: VTC - This question is not about the electronics design focus of the site. This makes it off topic here and I suggest that it may be more relevant on a craft site section of Stack Exchange. With that said the blade life will depend on how hot you get it, what you use it for and how you use it. So there really is not an good answer anyway.

Comment: x-acto knife blades are a consumable item (they are disposable). I suggest not to worry too much about it.

Comment: If your relying on the heat to do the cutting then it doesn't matter if the blade goes dull.

Comment: By the way, I have not tried this before. I will experiment with it. It sounds like a decent idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the blade is made from Steel, and Steel melts at around 1400°C, heating it up to a mere 350°C is not likely to do anything to it other than perhaps tarnish the surface.

Given also that it's not the blade that's "cutting" through the plastic but rather the heat of the soldering iron melting the plastic, it is probably somewhat irrelevant how sharp the blade remains, or whether or not it tarnishes.

I'd be more concerned about the soldering iron. Cutting through plastic leaves a nasty hard to clean residue. While it doesn't really matter if this gets on the blade, if it gets on your soldering iron tip you'll likely never be able to use the tip again for soldering. If you remove the tip and it gets on the heating element then it will degrade performance next time you try to put on a new tip by reducing heat transfer.